# Generar firma digital Google maps statics api

Tags: google-maps, algoritmos, vb6

¿Dónde puedo encontrar qué operaciones realiza el algoritmo (HMAC-SHA1) que emplea Google maps api para obtener la firma que se incorpora al final de la URL’s? Quiero programar en Visual Basic a partir de la URL y el “secreto de firma de URL” para obtener las firmas. Aunque si está disponible el código de alguien que ya lo haya hecho, perfecto.

Gracias anticipadas

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo de la firma que necesitas?

Comment: Sí: yFkqfJN-NQm_FCjr91Sq027bSbE  @dacoso

Comment: Tengo entendido que el hash te lo proporciona la pagina de google si quieres puedes revisar este recurso, para generarla tienes que tener una cuenta, mas info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=ES#obtn-una-clave-de-api

Comment: Tengo cuenta. Lo que proporciona Google es una herramienta, que está en el panel de control del cliente, que devuelve la URL firmada a partir da la URL sin firmar, pero se debe hacer de una en una y por un copia-pega. Lo que yo necesito es generar desde una app las URL's ya firmadas para enviarlas automáticamente al servidor de Google maps. @dacoso

Comment: Básicamente, si estás usando algo como esta [firma de url en php](https://gist.github.com/MattKetmo/6897944) lo que quieres es reproducir `hash_hmac("sha1",$url, $key,  true);` en visual basic. Revisa acá: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515164/visual-basic-2010-hmac-sha1

Comment: No me sirve. Tiene que ser un código de Visual Basic que pueda incorporar a B4A, que es el programa en el que estoy haciendo la app, y que dispone de pocas bibliotecas